# why appmanandroid_voice_recog is not listed on the Android Market

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to use https://kforge.ros.org/appmanandroid/voice_recoghg, but could not find on the Android Market.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11509/why-appmanandroid_voice_recog-is-not-listed-on-the-android-market/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2011-10-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The voice recog app is not ready for market release.  It interacts with software on the robot that is still under development.

The android portion of the app mainly just uses the builtin Android APIs for voice recognition and publishes that as a string to a topic.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2